# 2sxc shake edit buttons remain in sight

Tags: 2sxc

I installed 8.8. And shaking my phone like a maniac but the edit buttons remain in sight. Is that a known issue or should I be doing something different (like adjusting templates or something).

Kind regards
Tycho

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If a button is visible or not is configured at various levels. So it can be that your buttons are set to always visible - in which case the shake has no effect.

But if you're just using normal buttons which only appear on float, and they already appear (on desktop and mobile) without float/shake, then it's probably something different.

Best to do some more testing to corner the issue.

Comment: I tried starting the app with [Content:Toolbar]
This shows 3 buttons including edit button. Shaking is not enabling/disbling the buttons (no strange as it is not floating)

I tried starting the app with [Content:FloatingToolbar]
This shows 2 buttons but not the edit button. And is not shaking either.

I tried a page using one of the 27 bootstrap content apps (brilliant by the way) but that's not shaking either.

Comment: The buttons are always visible, if there is no area around it which would handle the mouse-over. Give a div around your toolbar the class "sc-element" and you should be good to go :)

Comment: works like a charm :-) 
Using <div class="sc-element">[Content:FloatingToolbar]</div>  does it. 

What I do miss, though, is the edit button that is present if I have 
Content:Toolbar]. Without the edit button I need to select 'content items' where I find the list and edit there. But I would love the return of the pencil icon :-)

Comment: Your last comment confuses me. There is no [Content:FloatingToolbar], only [Content:Toolbar] - just optionally with the "sc-element" class around it. It shouldn't affect which buttons appear, as it only controls floating.